# Why correlated subquery doesn't allow two expressions - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have query like this:

```
select 
    objectid,
    (select top 1 data_source, maxspeed
     from SpeedLimitData3
     where way_geometry.Filter(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + cast(X as varchar(15)) + ' ' + cast(Y as varchar(15)) + ')', 4326)) = 1
     order by way_geometry.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + cast(X as varchar(15)) + ' ' + cast(Y as varchar(15)) + ')', 4326))
    )
from 
    testData
```

Why does the SQL Server throw this error?

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I know that this means that I need to remove one of subquery's selected columns. But why when I have single row as subquery result and not several?

Comment: Just move your inner select into from part and make it cross apply, it will do the same thing and you can have more than one column

Comment: @JamesZ I already did that. My question is Why there in correlated subquery cann't be more than one expressions?

Comment: Your expression is in SELECT area, where only scalars have to be.

Comment: @DimaSUN I thought column + row of two columns = three columns, but it  seems it isn't :)

Comment: c my answer down here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of a [select clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) in Transact-SQL allows a `<select-list>` made up of various entities. A correlated [subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) used in a select clause is an `expression` and supplies the value for a single result column.

Answer (score 0):

this will work, but will output same data in otr.* part of select.
You have to use related fields in testData and applied correlation

```
select objectid, otr.*
from testData
outer apply
    (
    select top 1 data_source, maxspeed
    from SpeedLimitData3
    where way_geometry.Filter(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + cast(X as varchar(15)) + ' ' + cast(Y as varchar(15)) + ')', 4326)) = 1
    order by way_geometry.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + convert(varchar(15),X) + ' ' + convert(varchar(15),Y) + ')', 4326))
    ) otr
```

Comment: What are X, Y ? if they are fields in testData - I'll change my Query

Comment: Yes, they are from testData.

Answer (score 0):

If X & Y are fields in testData

```
select tD.objectid, otr.*
from testData tD
outer apply
    (
    select top 1 data_source, maxspeed
    from SpeedLimitData3
    where way_geometry.Filter(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + convert(varchar(15),tD.X) + ' ' + convert(varchar(15),tD.Y) + ')', 4326)) = 1
    order by way_geometry.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + convert(varchar(15),tD.X) + ' ' + convert(varchar(15),tD.Y) + ')', 4326))
    ) otr
```